# Overlay Image and Background Image Zooming with TouchImageView

Tags: android, imageview, touchimageview

How to make overlay image and background image zoom in and out at the same time using TouchImageView? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this library,

https://github.com/albinmathew/PhotoCrop

I hope it solve your problem...